# TLS RSA decryption fails with 'The parameter is incorrect'

Tags: c#, ssl, encryption, rsa

I am reposting from here after adding clarification. I edited the old post too late, so it doesn't go into the review queue for reopening: [Original Post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63309984/which-section-of-tls-packet-to-decrypt)

I writing a C# sniffer to decrypt a TLS packet which I already have the private key for. Here is a screenshot of the TLS packet.
[image]

I have tried decrypting the bytes in "Encrypted Application Data", but I am getting the error, "The parameter is incorrect" which usually means the data isn't correct for the provided key, so the question is, am I decrypting the wrong bytes?

The private key I have is from a .pem file in the section -----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----. I think this .pem file is generated from OpenSSL, and when I add this .pem file to Wireshark, Wireshark can display the Encrypted Application Data in cleartext.

Here is the code that's failing

```
    if (File.Exists(filename))
    {
        string strPEM = File.ReadAllText(filename);
        string strPriKey = GetStringFromPEM(strPEM, PEMStringType.PrivateKey);
        strPriKey = RsaPemFormatHelper.Pkcs8PrivateKeyFormatRemove(strPriKey);


        byte[] decryptedBytes;
        using (RSACryptoServiceProvider rsa = new RSACryptoServiceProvider(2048))
        {
            RSAParameters rsaPrivParam = CreateRsapFromPrivateKey(Convert.FromBase64String(strPriKey));
            rsa.ImportParameters(rsaPrivParam);

            // just to test rsa is able to encrypt and decrypt correctly with the private key
            string testString = "test123";
            var encrypted = rsa.Encrypt(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(testString), false);
            string encryptedString64 = Convert.ToBase64String(encrypted);

            var encrypted2 = Convert.FromBase64String(encryptedString64); // should be the same as encrypted
            var decrypted = rsa.Decrypt(encrypted2, false);
            string resultString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decrypted); // matches testString

            // actual decryption
            byte[] newArray = new byte[256];
            Array.Copy(encryptedBytes, 0, newArray, 0, 256); // encryptedBytes contains the bytes in Encrypted Application Data
            decryptedBytes = rsa.Decrypt(newArray, false); // <-- fails with 'The parameter is incorrect'
            string sbytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(decryptedBytes);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Sorry, still now allowed. I have however given you a hint below the closed question. Yeah, I don't like that part of the review queue either.

Comment: By the way, I think usually the questions still get into the queue but I'm not sure if enough people would vote for it, as the queue's on SO are pretty deep.

Comment: What is the ciphersuite?

Comment: cipher suite is TLS_RSA_WITH_AES256_CBC_SHA